# How to restore a specific collection with the use fo its data files in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, restore, database-backups, internals

I want to restore a specific collection from a mongodb database and I have its data files (of whole db) and I want to restore only one collection

also which data files get affected when there is any change in collection along with its collection-*.wt file and index files

NOTE: I dont want to use mongorestore and I have a sharded cluster

I tried simple copy and pasting of collection-*.wt , its related index file and _mdb_catalog file.

thank you.

Comment: why can't you dump a single collection and restore it?

Comment: I want to backup with data files. i could backup full database but in case of collection i need to know which files get affected when there is any change in collection so that backing those file and restoring would bring my desired collection back

Comment: @Astro I am using snapshot for backup its alternative to mongodump